# swig and C++11 compatibility

Tags: c++, c++11, swig

I'm trying to create a python module for a complex project that uses some of the new features in C++11 (https://code.google.com/p/cpp-array/). My interface file is very simple:

```
%module array

%{
#include "array-config.hpp"
#include "array.hpp"
%}
%include "array-config.hpp"
%include "array.hpp"
```

Yet when I run swig, I get lots of errors.

The first error is for a constexpr

```
constexpr static int dim()
{ return d; }
```

So if I remove the constexpr I can get around this error. According to the document in http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CPlusPlus11.html, this keyword is handled.

The second one is when this function is found:

```
template <int d, typename U, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value and !std::is_pointer<U>::value and d < k, void>::type
init(U i, Args&&... args) {

  assert(i != 0); // Array dimension cannot be zero
  n_[d] = i;
  init<d+1>(args...);
}
```

I'm just trying to use swig "for the truly lazy", but I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible at this point. Do I have to copy the entire header file and start making tweaks in order to make this work? I would really appreciate some suggestions as I'm new to swig.

Comment: can you give the actual error messages?

Comment: The error message is not very useful:
~Local/cpp-array/array/array.hpp:450: Error: Syntax error in input(3).

Comment: You have to instantiate templates before SWIG can hope to wrap them. That already will require a significant amount of code if you are starting from a heavily templatized library; so you might as well create a reduced interface that doesn't make use of `constexpr`, SFINAE, etc, and only feed that to SWIG.

Answer (score 1):

You can always wrap anything SWIG doesn't like inside an `#ifdef`

For example, I'm using C++11 blocks which aren't supported by the version of SWIG we use. So I do:

```
namespace glue {
    class GlueServer {
    public:
        virtual void handle(std::string path, GlueHandlerFunc handler, void* arg) = 0;    
#ifndef SWIG
        virtual void handleBlock(std::string path, void (^b)(GlueRequest* req)) = 0;
#endif

// ...
```